# How to prevent row from overflowing horizontally and instead show three dots in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

As you can see in my code a `Row` with `children`, currently the `Row` is overflowing because the width of the screen is too small. When the `Row` overflows on a certain child (in this case the 5th `Text("this is test 5")`, because then an error appears), instead of an error message, I  want three dots (...) to appear.
I've seen widgets like the `Wrap` widget where you can prevent overflowing, but then the overflowing `children` will appear in a `Column`. I don't want that, I want those overflowing to be replaced with three dots or a widget of my choice.

**What I want:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzhUc.png]

**Current result:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL7MZ.png]

**What I've tried:**

```dart
return const MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text("this is test 1"),
          Icon(
            Icons.circle,
            size: 5,
          ),
          Text("this is test 2"),
          Icon(
            Icons.circle,
            size: 5,
          ),
          Text("this is test 3"),
          Icon(
            Icons.circle,
            size: 5,
          ),
          Text("this is test 4"),
          Icon(
            Icons.circle,
            size: 5,
          ),
          Text("this is test 5"),
          Icon(
            Icons.circle,
            size: 5,
          ),
          Text("this is test 6"),
          Icon(
            Icons.circle,
            size: 5,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using flexible and also Text widget add the text overflow method **TextOverflow.ellipsis** (this will achieve dot when the text is overflowed to your end of the row text widget.

example :

```
Center(
        child: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("this is test 1"),
              Icon(
                Icons.circle,
                size: 5,
              ),
              Text("this is test 2"),
              Icon(
                Icons.circle,
                size: 5,
              ),
              Text("this is test 3"),
              Icon(
                Icons.circle,
                size: 5,
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.circle,
                size: 5,
              ),
              Text("this is test 5"),
              Icon(
                Icons.circle,
                size: 5,
              ),
              Flexible(child: Text("this is test 6",   style: TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),)),
              Icon(
                Icons.circle,
                size: 5,
              ),
              Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                "this is test 7",
                style: TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
              )),
              Flexible(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.circle,
                  size: 5,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

[image: example screenshot]

Here just an idea you can do with text widget.

Comment: thats right , the main point is text need to allow "style: TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)" but if there are dynamic count of strings and icon couples we can't handle this style like this static way. it must be always in our control there. so I am recommending this text and icon couple could be a widget and this widget's text allow overflow ellipsis

Comment: It works now, but I don't want the children to be replaced by ..., I just want the overflowing children to be removed and replaced by ...

Comment: @huzeyfetas but on a normal widget, `TextOverflow.ellipsis` can't be used right?

Comment: as far as I know textoverflow.ellipsis allow by text style. not for other widgets